# What wavelengths of lights do plants need to grow?

Tags: botany, light

So, I found a list of L.E.D.'s from Cree [here](http://www.cree.com/LED-Components-and-Modules/Applications/Color/Horticulture) (the company seems to be known for efficiency, they power most of the bicycle lights that I know of) is selling a line of lights designed for growing plants.  If you click on the data sheets, you'll find something like this:

[image]

Now, I know that plants reflect green preferentially because it is the least useful color to them (energetically speaking) so I assume that this matters.

I know the first few things about electronics, so I would really like to use one of these in something that I build.  However,the question becomes:

What kind of spectrum light and I looking for?  What is the difference between the "vertical farming" lights and the greenhouse lights?  (Viewing angle?

I kind of want to put some plants in a box coated internally with aluminum foil (it can reflect more than 90% of the energy), and hook one of these bad boys up for some inside growing.  Thanks alot.

Comment: A simple Google search using [the title of your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+wavelengths+of+lights+do+plants+need+to+grow%3F) will give you many resources. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more suitable for Physics.SE

Comment: The main question is also unclear.

Comment: I think the question is on-topic but unclear and lacking in effort (exactly what do you want to grow and at what scale? what do you know from before, and what information are you missing?).